# Good book on integral calculus (improper integrals, integrals with parameters, special functions)

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Can you recommend a good book (with theoretical results with proofs, and with plenty of solved problems and examples) on the topics of improper integrals, (improper) integrals with parameters, special functions (Beta, Gamma, ...)?

Comment: This [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176032/good-book-on-evaluating-difficult-definite-integrals-without-elementary-antider) may help.

Comment: I think I remember liking this book "An introduction to the theory of functions of a complex variable" by Copson, when I did a course on complex analysis last semester. He seems to do a good bit and I couldn't get through nearly half of it. It seems to be available here to read online: https://archive.org/details/TheoryOfTheFunctionsOfAComplexVariable

Comment: He does do a bit on special functions, gamma, beta, hypergeometric. Plus there's a search bar. It's from something like 1901 I think I read... Meant to be pretty decent though

Comment: an exercise book with solutions, http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Mathematical-Analysis-Student-Library/dp/0821832980

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look at the affordable and accessible Schaum's Outline of Advanced Calculus. Not too much advanced :)

Answer (score 1):

I like Hildebrand's 'Advanced Calculus for Applications'. It has many applications of special functions for differential equations and shows how to use them to solve problems.