# References on integration: collections of fully worked problems (and explanations) of (1) advanced and (2) unusual techniques

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, reference-request

I am searching for two kinds of books.

> **(1)** *Comprehensive* books that *collect*, *explain*, and provide many *examples* (that is, fully worked problems) of **advanced** integration techniques (that is,
>   something at the level of difficulty of the tables written by
>   Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, but obviously with explanations, examples and
>   proofs).
>
> **(2)** *Comprehensive* books that *collect*, *explain*, and provide many *examples* (that is, fully worked problems) of *really* **unusual** and **slick** integration
>   techniques (which may however not be so advanced or use special
>   functions).

Can you point out some good references?

---

**Related question:** "[Really advanced techniques of integration (definite or indefinite)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942263/really-advanced-techniques-of-integration-definite-or-indefinite)".

**Remark:** Clearly, an answer should add some references that *have not been mentioned yet* (either in the comments or in the related thread),.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0521791863?pc_redir=1410176046&robot_redir=1

Comment: Some suggestions: 

[1] G. Boros and V. Moll, *Irresistible Integrals: Symbolics, Analysis and Experiments in the Evaluation of Integrals*, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2004.

[2] I. S. Gradshteyn, I. M. Ryzhik, and D. Zwillinger (editor), *Table of Integrals, Series, and Products*, 8th edition, Academic Press, New York, 2008.

[3] P. J. Nahin, *Inside Interesting Integrals*, Springer, New York, 2014.

[4] D. Zwillinger, *The Handbook of Integration*, A K Peters/CRC Press, Boston, 1992.

Comment: Also, you can have a look at the references listed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176032/good-book-on-evaluating-difficult-definite-integrals-without-elementary-antider).

Comment: Thank you very much for these valuable references.

Comment: I know you don't have the background yet, but this book, though expensive, is quite a treasure chest: http://www.amazon.com/The-Cauchy-Method-Residues-Applications/dp/9027716234

Comment: @RonGordon I'll keep it in mind for when the time comes :)

Comment: Also, check this answer out as well.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765198/some-users-are-mind-bogglingly-skilled-at-integration-how-did-they-get-there/769444#769444

Comment: @RonGordon Wow. I'm simply amazed: that is a great answer. Again, thank you very much for being here.

Comment: Some of my notes http://folk.ntnu.no/oistes/Diverse/Integral%20Kokeboken.pdf =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the collected works of [Ron Gordon on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/53268/ron-gordon) is definitely worth mentioning!!

Comment: You are absolutely right: he is amazing.