# Evaluate $ \int_0^\pi \left( \frac{2 + 2\cos (x) - \cos((k-1)x) - 2\cos (kx) - \cos((k+1)x)}{1-\cos (2x)}\right) \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Evaluate the following definite integral:

$$ \int_0^\pi  \left( \frac{2 + 2\cos (x) - \cos((k-1)x) - 2\cos (kx) - \cos((k+1)x)}{1-\cos(2x)}\right) \mathrm{d}x, $$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$.

Comment: Where is this from by the way?

Comment: A classmate told me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let

$$I_k = \int_0^\pi  \left( \frac{2 + 2\cos x - \cos(k-1)x - 2\cos kx - \cos(k+1)x}{1 - \cos2x}\right) \mathrm dx.$$

Then, we have:

- $I_0 = 0$;
- $I_1 = \pi$.

For any  $ k \in \mathbb{N}^*$, we have:
$$ \begin{align} 
I_{k+1} - 2I_k + I_{k-1} 
&=  \int_0^\pi  \left(  \frac{\cos(-2+k)x - 2\cos kx + \cos (2 + k)x}{-1 + \cos 2x}\right) \mathrm dx \\
&= \int_0^\pi  \left(  \frac{2\cos kx(-1 + \cos^2x)}{-1 + \cos 2x}\right) \mathrm dx =0
\end{align}$$
Since $ I_{k+1} - I_k = I_k - I_{k-1} $, $(I_k)$ is an arithmetic progression. Hence $ I_k  = k\pi $.

Comment: *N.B.*: I remember that this trick was used to solve a similar integral from Teodora-Liliana T. Rădulescu, Vicenţiu D. Rădulescu, Titu Andreescu, *Problems in Real Analysis: Advanced Calculus on the Real Axis*, Springer, New York, 2009. Later, I will check and write a precise reference.

Comment: That's clever. Thank you very much.

Comment: Nice use of recursion.

Comment: Bonus problem: for half-integral values of $k$ the answers are rational numbers. Can you prove this/give a closed form?

Comment: @IgorRivin by half-integral you mean of the form $n+\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @Dal yes, exactly.

Comment: @RonGordon Thank you very much.

Comment: @IgorRivin Thanks for your interesting question: I will surely look into the problem when I have some free time.

Answer (score 4):

I think we can get the answer into a relatively elementary form.  Observe that

$$\cos{(k-1) x} + 2 \cos{k x} + \cos{(k+1) x} = 2 \cos{k x} (1+ \cos{x})$$

Thus the integrand simplifies into

$$4 \int_0^{\pi} dx \cos^2{\frac{x}{2}} \frac{\sin^2{k \frac{x}{2}}}{\sin^2{x}} $$

which is equal to

$$\frac12 \int_0^{2 \pi} du \left (\frac{\sin{k u}}{\sin{u}} \right )^2 $$

This integral may be evaluated using the residue theorem by converting it to a complex integral:

$$-\frac{i}{2} \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z^{2 k-1}} \left (\frac{z^{2 k}-1}{z^2-1} \right )^2$$

The only (non-removable) pole is at $z=0$, but this pole has multiplicity $2 k-1$.  Thus, by the residue theorem, the integral is equal to

$$\frac{\pi}{(2 k-2)!} \left [\frac{d^{2 k-2}}{dz^{2 k-2}} \left (\frac{z^{2 k}-1}{z^2-1} \right )^2 \right ]_{z=0} = \frac{\pi}{(2 k-2)!} \left [\frac{d^{2 k-2}}{dz^{2 k-2}} \left (1+z^2+z^4+\cdots z^{2 k-2} \right )^2 \right ]_{z=0}$$

Now, this may be evaluated as follows.  The derivative term is equal to

$$2 \frac{d^{2 k-3}}{dz^{2 k-3}} \left (1+z^2+z^4+\cdots z^{2 k-2} \right )^2 \left (2 z+4 z^3+\cdots+(2 k-2) z^{2 k-3} \right )$$

This is obviously a polynomial, and at $z=0$, the only surviving term will be the $z^{2 k-3}$ term.  The coefficient of that term is

$$2+4+6+\cdots+(2 k-2) = k (k-1)$$

Therefore, the integral is

$$\frac{2 \pi}{(2 k-2)!} k (k-1) (2 k-3)! = \pi k$$

**ADDENDUM**

In response to @Igor's challenge, I can at least show that the value of the integral for half-integer values of $k$ is a rational number.  (Note that the above analysis is only valid for integer $k$.)  For these values of $k$, the above contour integration does not work because the extension of the integration interval to $[0,2 \pi]$ does not apply.  Thus, the recurrence approach of @Nico is better here.  If we define

$$J_m = I_{m+\frac12}$$

Then the recurrence relation we seek is

$$J_{m+1}-2 J_m + J_{m-1} = 4 \frac{(-1)^m}{2 m+1}$$

Thus, to show that $J_m \in \mathbb{Q}$, we need only show that $J_0 \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $J_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$.  So we evaluate the integrals.

$$\begin{align}J_0 &= 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} du \frac{\sin^2{(u/2)}}{\sin^2{u}} \\ &= \frac12 \int_0^{\pi/2} du \, \sec^2{\frac{u}{2}} \\ &= \left [ \tan{\frac{u}{2}}\right ]_0^{\pi/2} = 1 \end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}J_1 &= 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} du \frac{\sin^2{(3 u/2)}}{\sin^2{u}} \\ &= \frac12 \int_0^{\pi/2} du \, \sec^2{\frac{u}{2}} (1+2 \cos{u})^2 \\ &= \left [ \tan{\frac{u}{2}} + 4 \sin{u}\right ]_0^{\pi/2} = 5 \end{align}$$

Thus, the $J_m \in \mathbb{Q}$ as asserted.

Comment: It seems a little too complicated for me, but thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  If you get to complex analysis, you will see that your integral is a natural for the methods taught there.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much again. I appreciate your skills, your great work and kindness very much :)

Comment: By the way, you have been mentioned in an answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959247/books-with-collections-of-unusual-and-advanced-integration-techniques)  of mine and I directly saw your skills. So I would like to ask you if you mind answering or commenting on that question and sharing some of your experiences.

Comment: @Dal: Oh my!  I'll have a hard time getting my head through the door today.

Comment: Extraordinary work as always.

Comment: My guess is:


$$ J_k= \frac{ -2 (-1)^k + (1 + 2k)(\pi + 2(-1)^k \Phi_k)}{2}, $$
where $\Phi_k = \Phi \Big(-1, 1, \frac{3+2k}{2}\Big)$ [see [1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html)].

Comment: @Nico: that's pretty much what Mathematica produces.  The LerchPhi is just a fancy way of saying the sum on my RHS.  I doubt you're going to get any simpler than that.  That's why I stopped at the proof of rationality.

Comment: You are perfectly right.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica says:

$$
-\frac{1}{2} i e^{-i \pi  k} \left(2 \pi  e^{i \pi  k} k \cot (\pi  k)+k \psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{k}{2}\right)-k \psi
   ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{k}{2}\right)+e^{2 i \pi  k} \left(k \psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)-k \psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)+1\right)+1\right)
$$

Comment: I have not tried it with WolframALpha

Comment: `Assuming[Element[k, Integers], 
 Integrate[(2 + 2 Cos[x] - Cos[(k - 1) x] - 2 Cos[k x] - 
     Cos[(k + 1) x])/(1 - Cos[2 x]), {x, 0, Pi}]]` works for Mathematica

Comment: No offense @IgorRivin, but this is a clear example of why it may not be a good idea to just leave evaluation of tough integrals and series to Mathematica/Maple.

Comment: @RonGordon If you don't mean offense, your statement is completely gratuitous.

Comment: @IgorRivin: how so?  You have posted output from Mathematica which suggests a seriously complicated result, when in fact the result is as simple as can be.  Perhaps I missed your point.

Comment: @RonGordon I posted output from Mathematica, because that is the answer, for any $k$. Nico's solution is very nice, and immediately shows that this is a made-up question, with a made-up trick to do it. So, not very interesting. In fact, there is a lot more going on (see, for example, my comment on the accepted answer).

On a different level, I saw the question, I had Mathematica open, I knew that I could potentially help the OP by using 30 seconds of my time. What exactly is the problem with that? Should I know a priori that this is a context problem?

Comment: @IgorRivin: perhaps it is a more general result.  But you yourself never said that.  In fact, you stated the opposite when explaining your input into Mathematica: your input states *explicitly* to assume that $k$ is an integer.  Someone like Dal who is looking for guidance, if this were the only answer, may get discouraged or confused by such a complicated result when in fact the result is simple.  That's all I am saying.

Comment: @RonGordon You are correct that the integer assumption is not necessary, and as for "confused or discouraged", I maintain that having a slick trick like the one in the accepted answer teaches the OP absolutely nothing. If s/he were to get the simple answer out of the mathematica formula (not so trivial), s/he might actually learn a lot.

Comment: Please, there is no need to argue. I just want to say that I appreciate all three answers because they give me different viewpoints and approaches and therefore all will (hopefully) help me get better.

Comment: @Dal: no need to worry.  I respect Igor and his terrific contributions here.  I was critical of this particular answer, and he disagrees.  I stated my peace as has he.  Typical sort of exchange here.

Comment: Indeed, the OP has a healthy approach - every different approach contributes something.