# How to calculate integrals like $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, book-recommendation

My question as hinted at in the headline, do you have a recommendations for a book, where explicitly these types of problems are discussed? No sure about $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ...dx$.

Comment: What is the level of math you know, that might help us in suggesting you references.

Comment: I am an undergrad. But this should not be a concern. I am willing to to dive deeply into the matter. maybe a book which is not so technical and a book which goes really into depth.

Comment: Here there is the proof: https://jakubmarian.com/integral-of-exp-x2-from-minus-infinity-to-infinity/

Comment: Check this page for resource reccommendation on books - https://math.stackexchange.com/q/176032/116937

A very introduction would be Schaum's series (Advanced calculus/Outline of Calculus)

Comment: Kinda. My Q was more general

Comment: Since you tagged [complex-analysis], see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aw9BfO0Whic) explaining a method to compute it via contour integral

Comment: You'd probably like 'Advanced Calculus Explored' by H. Alsamraee

Comment: Thanks guys, have noted them all!!!!

Answer (score 2):

This integral is very famous and is called the Gaussian integral. There is a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) dedicated to this integral where you can find multiple proofs that
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}. $$
As for studying integrals that involve infinite bounds (they are called improper integrals) you can read the great [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral).

Comment: Thanks, thats clarifying all. The english version of wiki is so much better than other languages.